# Has anyone managed to get SDL 2/3 working, without X, in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, framebuffer, sdl

I have Raspbian Jessie running on my Pi2. I am currently booting into LXDE. I want to disable X and run my SDL code directly on the framebuffer. Can someone point me to where I can find more information on how to do this?

P.S. I can see that I can write to `/dev/fb` directly, but is this hardware-accelerated?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036650/using-opengl-without-x-window-system

Answer (score 1):

Link with instructions to build SDL2 (no X) on Pi:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/
you will get hardware accelerated graphics with SDL2

For more fun just use dispmanx/EGL/OpenVG for hardware accelerated graphics.

---

A user here has reported that "The `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` compiler option found on the above link saved the day for me".  This output of this is applied as a shell command (i.e., it works like a kind of macro) when building applications to be linked against the library like this:

```
g++ -o program_name program_name.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

Comment: What is the working principle of that method? Framebuffer, or something else?

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.